# POST REST API call with json body is not working in play framework with java

Tags: java, api, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2

I am unable to call an API call in play framework with Java.
the code looks like a good, but the API call was not triggering(API call is working fine in Postman). I think it might be the issue related to threads and I am unable to write the async task in play framework, please someone help me.
Hoping the Best! Thanks in advance!

find the code of API calling in the controller file

```
public Result updateTripDetail() {
//few statements;
            String url = "https://medicines-XXX/MZIMRestServicesXXX/v1/XXXX";
            JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
            jsonBody.put("source_type", "XXX");
            jsonBody.put("omorder_id", "25852");
            if (Rescheduled.equals(ride.getRideStatus())) {
                jsonBody.put("order_status", "RequestForReschedule");
            } else if (RideCancelled.equals(ride.getRideStatus())) {
                jsonBody.put("order_status", "RequestForCancel");
            } else {
                jsonBody.put("order_status", ride.getRideStatus());
            }
            jsonBody.put("last_updated_on", new Date());
            apiPostCall(url,jsonBody.toString());
    return redirect("/ride/rideList");
}

public void apiPostCall(String completeUrl, String body) {
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(completeUrl);
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    try {
        StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(body);
        httpPost.getRequestLine();
        httpPost.setEntity(stringEntity);
        httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use the WS API? https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaWS

Comment: The code that you're having problems with is not part of the Play framework and you don't specify anything about those classes. It's also rather vague what the actual problem / error is. It would help if you clarify these things.

Comment: Did you try debugging, when you run it, does it reach to the execute call?

Comment: ya, Jaanus, I have done debugging too, the apiPostCall() function is calling but not getting any response.

Comment: Does it reach the execute function? Since it is void function, how do you know it is not getting any response?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you are not using play commands for your HTTP request. Your code should be as follows:

```
public void updateTripDetail() {
//few statements;
            String url = "https://medicines-XXX/MZIMRestServicesXXX/v1/XXXX";
            JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
            jsonBody.put("source_type", "XXX");
            jsonBody.put("omorder_id", "25852");
            if (Rescheduled.equals(ride.getRideStatus())) {
                jsonBody.put("order_status", "RequestForReschedule");
            } else if (RideCancelled.equals(ride.getRideStatus())) {
                jsonBody.put("order_status", "RequestForCancel");
            } else {
                    jsonBody.put("order_status", ride.getRideStatus());
                }
                jsonBody.put("last_updated_on", new Date());
                apiPostCall(url,jsonBody.toString());
        //As an asynchronous request it would 
        //probably redirect before completing your request so void it's okay
        //return redirect("/ride/rideList");
    }
```

---

```
public Promise<Result> apiPostCall(String completeUrl, String body) {
        return WS.url(completeUrl)
                .setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .post(body).map(
                        new F.Function<WS.Response, Result>() {
                            public Result apply(WS.Response response) {
                                //you can handle your response here
                                //String token = response.asJson().findPath("access_token").asText();
                                return redirect("/ride/rideList");
                            }
                        }
                );
    }
```